# Best way to read (MATLAB) structures from a text file in Clojure / Incanter

Tags: matlab, text, clojure, struct

I exported my matlab structs to text files so that I can read them in clojure.
I have a text file like:

```
name
Ali
age
33
friends-ages
30
31
25
47
```

know I can read this file, but what's the clojure way to convert it into something like:

```
(def person1 
    {:name "Ali"
     :age  33
     :friends-ages [30 31 25 47]})
```

or lets make it easier:

```
name
Ali
age
33
```

to:

```
(def person1 
    {:name "Ali"
     :age  33})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an .m file to export my .mat files to text, then imported them by something like the following:

```
(use '[clojure.string :only (split join)])

(defn kv [[k v]] 
  [(keyword k) v])

(let [a (split (slurp (java.io.FileReader. fileName)) #"\n")]
      (def testNeuron (into {} (map kv (partition 2 a)))))
```

Thanks to the answers by Hamza and Jouni.
The actual code is more like this:

```
(def dataPath "/home/ali/Dropbox/Projects/Neurojure/")
(def testFileName "dae062.c1.cylinder.DID.txt")

(defn kv [[k v]] 
  [(keyword k)
  (if (< 0 (count (re-seq #"\d\d\d\dSpikes|\d\d\d\dOcodes|\d\d\d\dOSpikes" k)))
    (into [] (map (fn [x] (Integer/valueOf x)) (split v #",")))
   (try (Integer/valueOf v) 
     (catch NumberFormatException _ v)))])


(let [a (split (slurp (java.io.FileReader. (str dataPath testFileName))) #"\n")]
      (def testNeuron (into {} (map kv (partition 2 a)))))
```

and the converted data file looks like this:

```
ConvertDate
18-Nov-2011
Name
/bgc/data/dae/062/dae062.mat
frameperiod
83.2500000037253
Spike2Version
1.27
unstored
167
rfstr
cm=rf-3.10,9.61:0.00x0.00,-135deg pe20 -2.0,-3.0 fx=0.00,fy=0.00cm=rf-3.10,9.61:0.00x0.00,-135deg pe20 -2.0,-3.0 fx=0.00,fy=0.00
rf
-3.1,9.61,0,0,-135,20,-2,-3,0,0
trange
47371169.75,100193717.5
psych
1
rc
0
Options

expname
cylinder.dxXIdD
Start
94745610.75
End
100193717.5
Area
MT
Ex
perimenter Ali
Trial=>0001Start
47377343
Trial=>0001TrialStart
47377343
Trial=>0001End
47397224.25
Trial=>0001dur
19881.2500000075
Trial=>0001uStim
0
Trial=>0001op
40980
Trial=>0001Trial
1860
Trial=>0001id
15897
Trial=>0001Startev
47377149.5
Trial=>0001serdelay
-46.25
Trial=>0001bstimes
47377195.75
Trial=>0001delay
147.25
Trial=>0001TrueEnd
47397224.25
Trial=>0001CorLoop
0
Trial=>0001dx
0
Trial=>0001Spikes
-1402,-1232,1577,1931,2165,2222,2478,2773,2903,3229,3745,3820,4071,4588,4920,5141,5752,6440,6490,6664,6770,7042,7958,8081,8307,8622,8732,9021,9082,9343,9619,9695,9877,10357,10668,10943,11105,11364,11720,12272,12499,12762,12907,13621,14121,14351,14542,14588,15104,15420,15501,16331,16596,16843,17476,17698,17996,18169,18401,18532,18706,19029,19081,19418,19603,19750,20222
Trial=>0001count
65
Trial=>0001OptionCode
+do+aa+sq+72+se+fc+fb+ap+wt+cf+ws+ts+sw+bw+cs+2a+bm+gm+x2+sp+da+ao+cS+C3+CF
Trial=>0001me
0
Trial=>0001OSpikes
-1976,-1802,-1423,-1360,-1268,-1248,-1140,-244,-220,-164,632,681,730,760,779,786,867,879,924,1062,1161,1252,1268,1431,1533,1632,1946,2210,2235,2273,2285,2296,2305,2496,2532,2541,2732,2787,2806,2822,2840,3095,3292,3431,3598,3614,3837,4100,4482,4504,4515,4651,4768,4794,4936,5020,5160,5184,5300,5314,5710,5764,6431,6453,6471,6553,6561,6584,6791,7018,7124,7880,7905,7940,7968,8011,8315,8330,8352,8568,8666,8748,8756,8766,8797,8836,9038,9297,9328,9360,9471,9632,9639,9721,9939,10196,10363,10375,10387,10410,10931,10953,10969,10986,11038,11118,11135,11405,11692,12018,12163,12258,12492,12512,12525,12884,12899,12919,13156,13183,13638,13674,13842,13988,14110,14298,14310,14321,14606,14617,15124,15132,15150,15289,15341,15620,16293,16305,16342,16364,16441,16604,16692,16932,16997,17059,17086,17210,17368,17495,17626,17639,17651,17677,17718,18013,18247,18353,18553,18691,18722,18887,18941,19438,19774,19938,19959,19967,20004,20240,20306,20500,20623
Trial=>0002Start
47406914
Trial=>0002TrialStart
47406914
Trial=>0002End
47426795.25
Trial=>0002dur
19881.2499999925
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming each file has a single record,

```
(defn parse [f]
  (let [[_ name _ age _ & friends] (.split (slurp f) "\n")]
    {:name name :age age :friends (map read-string friends)}))

(parse "../../../Desktop/t.txt")
```

you get,

```
{:name "Ali", :age "33", :friends-ages (30 31 25 47)}
```

Comment: Cool! But what if there are records that miss a property, like if there is no "age" for a record. Is there a way here to deal with that?

Comment: you can't do that unless you define a delimeter between keys.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you would need to manually do this conversion from text file (which isn't in any standard serialization formats) to the required set format. If possible, I would suggest that you should extract the MATLAB data in JSON format and that would be easy to read in clojure using the json library.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for your easier problem:

```
(ns example
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(def input "name\nAli\nage\n33\n") ; you'd get this by reading the file

(defn process [data]
  (->> (str/split data #"\n")
       (partition 2)
       (map (fn [[k v]]
              [(keyword k)
               (try
                 (Integer/valueOf v)
                 (catch NumberFormatException _
                   v))]))
       (into {})))

(prn (process input))
```

The full problem requires better specification of the format: how do you know that the list of ages is done?

Comment: Fantastic, what is `valueOf` I can't find it in clojuredocs.org ?

Comment: @Ali that is a java call, that will parse the str into a Integer.

Comment: @Jouni, instead of map then into you can just reduce the seq into a map after partition, that would make it cleaner.